# Invalid system id - Liferay Portal - Java Server Faces

Tags: jsf, liferay

I try to deploy portlets application to Liferay portal (I'm a maintainer, not the author).

But I get an exception:

```
08:08:48,060 ERROR [AutoDeployDir:197] com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.Aut
oDeployException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.DocumentException: Invalid syste
m id classpath:/com/sun/faces/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd Nested exception: Invalid
system id classpath:/com/sun/faces/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd
com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: com.liferay.portal.ke
rnel.xml.DocumentException: Invalid system id classpath:/com/sun/faces/web-faces
config_2_0.xsd Nested exception: Invalid system id classpath:/com/sun/faces/web-
facesconfig_2_0.xsd
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.auto.PortletAutoDeployer.autoDeploy(Portlet
AutoDeployer.java:99)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.auto.PortletAutoDeployListener.deploy(Portl
etAutoDeployListener.java:78)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.processFile(AutoD
eployDir.java:180)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.scanDirectory(Aut
oDeployDir.java:222)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner.run(AutoDeplo
yScanner.java:50)
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.DocumentException: Invalid system id cl
asspath:/com/sun/faces/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd Nested exception: Invalid system
id classpath:/com/sun/faces/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd
        at com.liferay.portal.xml.SAXReaderImpl.read(SAXReaderImpl.java:339)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.SAXReaderUtil.read(SAXReaderUtil.java:1
27)
        at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.PortletDeployer.setupJSF(PortletDeplo
yer.java:429)
        at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.PortletDeployer.getExtraContent(Portl
etDeployer.java:146)
        at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.updateWebXml(BaseDeploye
r.java:1789)
        at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.deployDirectory(BaseDepl
oyer.java:530)
        at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.deployFile(BaseDeployer.
java:889)
        at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.deployFile(BaseDeployer.
java:819)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.auto.PortletAutoDeployer.autoDeploy(Portlet
AutoDeployer.java:96)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Invalid system id classpath:/com/sun/fac
es/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd Nested exception: Invalid system id classpath:/com/su
n/faces/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd
        at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
        at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:264)
        at com.liferay.portal.xml.SAXReaderImpl.read(SAXReaderImpl.java:336)
        ... 12 more
```

Since it is not in my allication's code I have no idea what is wrong :(
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Invalid system id classpath:/com/sun/faces/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd
> ```

This exception suggests that you've a `faces-config.xml` file which is for some reason incorrectly declared like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee /com/sun/faces/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```

instead of

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```

Comment: I solved this problem by downgrading from Liferay 6.1 to 6.0.6 but thanks - I'll fix it for future compatibility.